# Emgu CV display GpuImage

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

I am using Emgu.CV for some video processing frame by frame. After I grab a frame from the Capture instance I convert the Image to GpuImage to do some GPU processing.

Is it possible to directly display the GpuImage without going back to Image?

My UI is on WPF.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: This here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496729/drawing-in-opencv-with-opengl is the closest thing I have found. Probably the right way is to do it with D3DImage which is an ImageSource but usage is extremely convoluted. I will post an update if I have a chance to implement that kind of control in time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to display a GpuImage in an Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox:

I have tested this in: emgucv-windows-universal-gpu 2.4.9.1847

```
// Create a new GpuImage and assign its value from Image.
GpuImage<Bgr, byte> gpuImage = new GpuImage<Bgr, byte>(image);

// Show the GpuImage in the ImageBox.
this.imageBox.Image = gpuImage;
```

This solution is the best that I can see but either way even if one was to convert the GpuImage back to an Image it is easy and fast:

```
// Create a new Image and convert the GpuImage to it.
Image<Bgr, byte> image = gpuImage.ToImage();

// Show the GpuImage in the ImageBox.
this.imageBox.Image = image;
```

Hope this helps!

Emgu is an excellent resource once an understanding is obtained. Its very well laid out and programmed. GPU Processing is definitely the way to go however.

Comment: What I am searching for is a way to avoid downloading the GpuImage form the GPU memory. ImageBox always downloads :( . This is usually a bottleneck for me in real time image processing.