# Drawing in OpenCV with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv

OpenCV library, when compiled with GPU and OpenGL support, allows for displaying images with OpenGL. For example, `video_reader.cpp` (located in gpu samples) uses OpenGL to render display graphics directly from `cv::gpu::GpuMat`.

```
cv::gpu::GpuMat d_frame;
namedWindow("OpenGL", WINDOW_OPENGL);
cv::gpu::VideoReader_GPU d_reader(fname);
d_reader.dumpFormat(std::cout);
if (!d_reader.read(d_frame))
    break;
cv::imshow("GPU", d_frame);
```

This is a very useful feature. However, it is not documented in the [documentation on-line](http://docs.opencv.org/index.html). For example, for [`namedWindow`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow#cv.NamedWindow) the flag `WINDOW_OPENGL` is not listed in the docs. Where can I find the documentation for OpenGL -related functionality of OpenCV?

Comment: The doc does not cover every feature. The day before, I found out that C API method cvLinearPolar (by which you can map a circular object to a rectangle) has no reference at all. There are many features missing from old API. I hope the authorized ones review the project and update the documentation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is not very complete for 2.4.5. I don't think there is any more documentation than what you see on http://docs.opencv.org.

There are older documentation, such as http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/ for 2.1, but I didn't find it having the documentation for the flag that you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

- OpenCV/OpenGL interop documentation
  https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/d3c/group__core__opengl.html
- Highgui/OpenGL documentation
  https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d24/group__highgui__opengl.html

Especially the second link gives you two easy options for rendering.

- `imshow` with a `Texture2D` object
- `setOpenGlDrawCallback()` (https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d24/group__highgui__opengl.html#gaf80dcbc168a6ce40f6d1ad9d79a10bb8) which allows you to draw on top of a `nameWindow("OpenGL Window", WINDOW_OPENGL)` using OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
cv::imshow(const & string, cv::InputArray)
```

does not natively support gpu matrices, but supports GPU matrices by casting.

i.e. anything which supports a `cv::Mat` on its input should also support `cv::gpu::GpuMat`. I presume this means that when you call the function, it will automatically download the matrix to a `cv::Mat` and go from there, i.e. your `imshow` function call is not drawing directly gpu->gpu, but going gpu->cpu->gpu.